# Null value of a given key of $_POST in PHP

Tags: php, post

I am trying to parse $_POST to get key

```
// Content of $_POST with valid key
Array ( [tree] => {"id":1,"name":"abcd"} [key] => "5hf7tr78" )


// Content of $_POST with null key
Array ( [tree] => {"id":1,"name":"abcd"} [key] => null )
```

My method

```
public function get_url() {
        if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
          foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
              if($key == 'key') {
                return $value;
              } 
            } 
          }
        }
        return null;
    }

$post_content = $this->get_url();
Print_r($post_content);
if(!isset($post_content) || empty($post_content)){
    $this->regenerate();
}
```

The code works fine when the key is present in the array, it will `print_r` the result properly. But when the key is null, nothing is printed by `print_R` and the `regenerate()` method doesn't get called. The `regenerate()` method needs to be called when the key is null;

Comment: What you want the get_url function to do? The way it Is, it Will behave quite randomly. It May return post value of any index depending on how you post the data.

Comment: forgot to add the if clause. I have updated the condition.

Comment: If i add for debug echo like this : `if(!isset($post_content) || empty($post_content)){
    echo "here";
} ` i can see "here". Could the problem be inside the regenerate function?